# iTunes OS X full system crash cont'd: is a bad media file the culprit? How do I isolate it?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, shell, crash

**THE ANSWER — NO SOLUTION**

It seems that this is a (hardware?) bug with the Intel iMacs and Mac Minis, as I discovered in this thread on [Apple Support](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2241023&start=0&tstart=0) (which admittedly wasn't easy to find with that title, but it fits my problem to a tee).

Going to have to wait for Apple to come up with a fix. Ire rising…

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Essentially, I had numerous system crashes caused (it seems) by iTunes downloading media: the system would hang irrecoverably. I couldn't even log in over SSH, though CoreGraphics continued to let me move windows around.

For more information on the background to this problem, please consult [iTunes causes the entire system to crash when downloading some media OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/211950/)

Becoming frustrated, I decided to perform a clean install of OS X. After wiping and installing OS X 10.6 (as case-sensitive and journaled, which I had used in past but had not used on my last install) and the Combo 10.6.5 (and all other relevant) updates, I began restoring my machine's data from Time Machine.

I restored preferences, documents and my Aperture library in separate restore batches. But when it came time to restore my iTunes Music Library (i.e., ~/Music/*) the system crashed part-way through writing files in a very similar manner: the cursor would move on the screen but the system was otherwise totally unresponsive, including SSH.

I can only surmise that the culprit lies somewhere in my 385 GB of media, which represents about 35 000 individual files. It's likely a file which is corrupted:

1. The **file name uses characters** that the system, for whatever reason, can't handle. I have a large number of file names that contain both Arabic or Hebrew (which are both right-to-left languages) *and* English. I also have a number of file names in Cyrillic, French and other languages. The Terminal doesn't seem to have a problem displaying them and I've never had trouble copying them either in the shell or in the Finder. Seems worth mentioning, anyway.
2. I may have somehow added a file which is corrupted or which violates Apple's allowable file **naming scheme** (say, containing null characters).
3. Some sort of **permissions error** in a subfolder. I repair permissions regularly, but as we know, it may not modify permissions of files which can "function with different permissions".

I now have two problems: (1) how do I determine if this is a file name or file-related problem; and (2) how do I figure out which file is the culprit? system.log and Console.app's "Diagnostic and Usage Messages" have no useful output. Furthermore, restoring the files manually from the Time Machine volume using `cp -Rnv time_machine ~/Music/` has worked and not caused an error.

I should add that I have preserved my iTunes Library (not just the files but the actual .xml file) since 2005, restoring from backups on OS and hardware upgrades. I would be surprised if I had not introduced corruption along the way from all that manipulation, chiefly filesystem changes (starting at Mac OS 9, migrating to and from case-sensitive volumes) over the years...

I'd appreciate any advice. The AKB hasn't been particularly helpful.

**EDIT (QTKitServer):** An AKB article on QTKitServer being a CPU hog got me thinking, especially after I saw it in Spin Control: perhaps that's the process that's bugging out at some point; I've just disabled Finder's show icon previews. I guess we'll see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is: disable Podcasts in iTunes completely. Sucky.